# How to dynamically access to a given pandas dataframe column in django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, pandas, plotly

I have some indicator objects and each indicator has an attribute content which contains a pandas dataframe. One can have access to such a content by using the accessor getContent of an indicator object. An indicator can be either univariate or multi-variate. A multi-variate one has multiple columns.

I do not know in advance the name of the columns of those pandas dataframes. But, I would like to have access to those columns in a Django template so that I can plot the indicator. Basically, one can iterate on a pandas dataframe by using the attribute '.columns'. But it seems it doesn't work.

Please find below what I tried, I would add that my goal is to do some plotting using Plotly :

```
<script>
Some code with the container definition ...
{% if indicator.isUnivariate %}
    Plotly.plot(
        container,
        [
            {
                x: [{% for x in indicator.getContent.index.values|slice:":-1" %}"{{ x }}",{% endfor %}],
                y: [{% for y in indicator.getContent.y.values|slice:":-1" %}{{ y }}, {% endfor %}],
                name: '{{ indicator.getId }}',
                mode: 'lines+markers',
                type: 'scatter'
            }
        ],
        {
            xaxis: {title: {text: "Calendar months"}},
            yaxis: {title: {text: "Indicator values"}},
        }
    );
{% else %}
    alert(indicator.getId)
    Plotly.plot(
        container,
        [
            {% for column in indicator.getContent.columns %}
                {
                    x: [{% for x in indicator.getContent.index.values|slice:":-1" %}"{{ x }}",{% endfor %}],
                    y: [{% for y in column.values|slice:":-1" %}{{ y }}, {% endfor %}],
                    name: '{{ column }}',
                    mode: 'lines+markers',
                    type: 'scatter'
                }
            {% endfor %}
        ],
        {
            xaxis: {title: {text: "Calendar months"}},
            yaxis: {title: {text: "Indicator values"}},
        }
    );
{% endif %}
</script>
```

The exception :
**django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: indicator.getContent|[column].values||slice:":-1"**

Hope it's clear, do not hesitate to let me know if you want more details.
Thanks :)

Comment: if you have `column` why do then do `indicator.getContent[column]`? You can't subscript in Django templates, so `[column]` doesn't work. And it's not the index, in the column itself. But you already have the `column` so `{% for y in column.values|slice:":-1" %}` should work

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. It seems it doesn't work but it may due to the details I gave you. I thus edited my original post to add more explanations and a larger part of code. Thanks :)

Comment: I highly suggest you completely rework your code to limit Django's rendering inside of the <script> tag to a single line of code where you parse JSON.

You're mixing controller logic with template logic, and rendering JavaScript dynamically. This is an anti-pattern. Prepare your data in your views, do JSON.dump(context) and then parse the JSON string in your template and work on the data in JavaScript.

The templating engine is not made for computations: that's why you have views.py

Comment: I note your remarks @Saturnix but I think my data is quite prepared, at least for what I want to do. Basically, each indicator content has an index, and some columns that correspond to the values of the indicators (depending on whether it is univariate or not). So, I just want to have access to those columns.

Comment: Please tell us what the error is in the new template. The error shown cannot happen anymore.

Comment: I resolved my problem thanks to your remarks @dirkgroten There were no errors, but no results as well. It was due to my views.py code. You helped me to understand something about Django templates. Thank you Saturnix for your remarks as well.